# Retrieve payer's country and payout info Apple In-App purchases API

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I didn't found any field in App Receipt/In-App purchase receipt fields to find the country of the user who has made an in-app purchase.

I used this url: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1 but also there is nothing that helps me to figure out the country from the paying user. I cannot use the IP because this can differ when somebody is on holiday.

My question is: is there a way in the Apple API for in-app purchases to find the payer's country and most ideally the payout of the amount he has paid?

For your info: I used StoreKit API and REST API from Apple which can be found on sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

Comment: For context, can you please explain why you need the country info?

Comment: we need to know this because we wanna save per user the revenues so we can use this for campaign optimization.
and by knowing the country we know what the payout is using the pricing matrix from Apple.

Comment: Thanks Gregory. I think Sanniv's answer is probably correct - we've done something similar. Additionally, our apps offer IAP in all countries, but the final payments into our bank account are always in our local currency (GBP). There are some losses and gains with currency conversions, but these average out and you can determine a general revenue model per price tier. Additionally, Apple will often change the payout rates for different regions (because of currency fluctuations) , so it would be a considerable effort mainting your ROI model with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

IAP Receipt doesn't contain country or payment info, the way I implemented, was to add User Info along with receipt while sending the same to my backend script for verification, and then using that user info, credit the respective user for given product id.
I guess you need to ask country info when user signs up in your app or may be use Facebook login.
Product cost can be checked using product id in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer Sanniv. But in this case, when an iOS user who is from the US is traveling to for example the Netherlands, will be marked as a payer from the Netherlands while in fact the Apple user is from the US and also pays in USD etc.. So I need the 'native' country from this user.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear in my answer. User Info like name, country, etc, is collected by the app from User when user signs up. So even if user travels to Netherland, in your database, user will still be from US.

Comment: And if you want to take country programmatically, you can use below method, this also give user's 'native' country. 
+(NSString*)getCountryName
{
    NSLocale* currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];  // get the current locale.
    NSString* countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
    
    NSString *country = [currentLocale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode];
    
    return country;
}